# Workday system event outbound subscriptions

Tags: events, workday-api

We are working on a use-case where in we need to get real time updates from Workday systems for the events occurring in Workday Systems.

I have read some articles stating that this can be achieved using Workday Event Subscription capabilities. However I did not found detailed public documentation available describing configuration to achieve this.

Does anyone have done this kind of use case, few configuration steps or references would be helpful.

I am a newbie in Workday, so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with the [Notification wsdl](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Notification/v30.0/Notification.html). You can create a subscription to the events you're looking for, and then trigger any appropriate messages after.